# Why instances created with Activator.CreateInstance do not resolve references?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, .net-assembly, fusion

I have an application with the following folder structure:

```
Application\Modules\XXX
```

Of course any assembly inside XXX finds other assemblies inside the XXX.

The problem happens with some instances that are instantiated used reflection:

```
TProvider providerInstance = (TProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(providerType));
```

TProvider has a method that returns a class defined in another assembly (stored in XXX as well). When calling that method of the providerInstance that has to load a reference I'm getting a FileNotFoundException about not finding the dependent assembly even when the dependency is in the same XXX folder.

Looking at the fusion log the assembly loader is only checking on the Application folder, not the XXX ...

Any idea on why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Assembly loading and the way you created object instance are not related to each other. `<probing privatePath="Modules\XXX"/>` should help you.

Comment: @Dennis: there are some dependences that are only resolved when calling some methods of the providerInstance. If the method of providerInstance will return a class defined on another assembly that class will only be reolved when calling the method for the first time. If I create the instance with ActivatorInstance it fails. If I create it normally it works.

Comment: @Dennis: and I shouldn't need that because all the assemblies are located on the same folder.

Comment: I think, you're misunderstanding assembly loading and resolving mechanism. How do you get `providerType`? Via `Assembly.Load`/`LoadFrom` and then enumerating through types?

Comment: @Dennis: I'm loading them with Assembly.LoadFile(filename) and then I search for some specific types, yes.

Comment: `LoadFile` does not load files into the LoadFrom context, and **does not resolve dependencies using the load path**, as the `LoadFrom` method does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that was the reason. Please add that as a response and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is in that you're loading assembly with [`LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) method:

> LoadFile does not load files into the LoadFrom context, and **does not
>   resolve dependencies using the load path, as the LoadFrom method does**.

You should use [`LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) method and load-from context, or, better, if it is possible, use [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) and load context.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm loading them with Assembly.LoadFile(filename)

That's a very common mistake.  It is often made because only LoadFile() has a decent MSDN article that doesn't read like gobbledegook, loading contexts are a very abstract concept in .NET.

LoadFile() should only ever be used if you intentionally **don't** want dependent assemblies to be found.  Which is quite rare, only programs that do things like inspect assemblies would do so.  Tools like disassemblers.

LoadFrom() is required to get the CLR to also look in that directory for dependent assemblies.  In general beware that this isn't a guaranteed fix for DLL Hell, the identity of a type includes the assembly it came from.  Things go wrong with a type with the same namespace name and type name exists in more than one assembly.  A failure mode that gets more likely with groups of assemblies in a separate directory.  Especially when you don't control its content, like a plug-in scenario.  Mystifying InvalidCastExceptions may be your next nemesis, also a very common failure mode for assemblies loaded with LoadFile().  Programmers like to organize files into directories, a bit of OCD that's a professional liability and pretty incompatible with the way the CLR likes to avoid DLL Hell.  If this is a requirement for a plug-in scenario then do favor an well worn plug-in framework like MEF to limit the mishaps.

Comment: Thanks Hans. All our development is inside the XXX folder as we are working in a big team with a PRISM application and our responsibility starts and ends in the XXX folder. Then probably the DLL hell cannot happen when you're restricted to one folder.

Answer (score 0):

To instruct the CLR to probe under the Modules\XXX subdirectory, create a new configuration file
named `applicationname.exe.config` using any text editor or use the supplied App.config file, and save the file in the folder containing the
`applicationname.exe` application, which, in this example is Application.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="Modules\XXX"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

say you want to specify an assembly using absolute path or relative one (not in same directory hierarchy as the .exe) , use `<codebase>` instead, anyway these two approaches are bound to the usage of xml configuration files.

> Assembly.LoadFrom(...)

Is indeed `<codebase>` equivalent; can take both relative and absolute paths

main reference: Pro C# 5.0 and .net 4.5